# How to monitor audio level without recording in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am using Qt 5.5.1 and I want to enable audio level monitoring. I looked through [AudioRecorder example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-example.html) and understood how to monitor levels while recording. Now I want to monitor audio level without starting recording. The [QAudioProbe class documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html#details) says:

> The QAudioProbe class allows you to monitor audio being played or
>   recorded.

And the sample code from the QAudioProbe  documentation is as follows:

```
QAudioRecorder *recorder = new QAudioRecorder();
QAudioProbe *probe = new QAudioProbe;

// ... configure the audio recorder (skipped)

connect(probe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), this, SLOT(processBuffer(QAudioBuffer)));

probe->setSource(recorder); // Returns true, hopefully.

recorder->record(); // Now we can do things like calculating levels or performing an FFT
```

Does it mean that one *must* start the recording or playback to collect the audio probes? I guess I can start a fake recording into some temporary location, but not sure if it's the right way. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is a shelf in our office, can you tell me how long it is without seeing it? Same is for audio, you will have to record/playback a sample to scan (probe) for the audio level.

Comment: Sebastian, I understand you. But the question is, can I do this without actually creating an output file? Can I start the recording without setting any output location?

Comment: Dmitry: `QAudioProbe::setSource()` works with either `QAudioRecorder` or with `QMediaObject` as source (see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioprobe.html). If you intent to monitor random system audio output that is not defined or accessed by your local code (and thus: inside either an `QAudioRecorder` or `QMediaObject`), this is not the way to go. See also: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaobject.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaservice.html .